# Finding articulation point with dfs_low and dfs_num

Tags: algorithm

I am reading on algorithms to find articulation point in a graph.

```
When we are in vertex u and v is its neighbor, then if dfs_low(v) >= dfs_num(u) then u is a cut vertex
```

`dfs_num(i)` numbers the vertex as seen in dfs.

`dfs_low(i)` tells the lowest numbered vertex reachable from i other than its parent.

I am wondering how this algorithm works for a 3 node cycle. (Looks like a triangle).

Running this algorithm, I get (where i = 0, 1, 2)

```
dfs_num(i) = i
dfs_num(i) = 0
```

This will return 0 as the cut vertex which is clearly not an articulation point.
I believe I have some misunderstanding here. Can someone please clarify it?

Comment: it should be dfs_low(i) = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root is a special case because it has no parent.  The root is an articulation point if it has more than one child in the DFS tree.  A non-root node `v` is an articulation point if and only if it has a subtree with no back edges pointing at ancestors of `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Another less abstract way to make sense of this idea is to picture just the DFS tree (not the entire graph) of your graph.

If the root of this tree has one child, then you know that removing it would be like removing the end point of a single line. For example, if A is the root:

**before removal:**
A--B--C--D

**after removal:**
B--C--D

However if the root has more than one child, then you can visualize that removing it would separate these two children, who now have no way to get to each other (for if they did, the DFS traversal would have found that edge between them and the root of the DFS tree would have only one child). For example:

**Before removal:**

[image]

**After removal:**

[image]

Therefore since removing this node breaks the graph into two or more pieces that cannot reach each other, it is an articulation point.